# Converting a HQL-query which includes elements() to Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api

I'm having trouble converting the following HQL-query to Criteria API and I was wondering if I could get some help from you guys

```
SELECT child FROM Foo AS child 
WHERE child IN (SELECT elements(obj.foos) FROM Bar AS obj WHERE obj.id = ?)
```

In other words, I want to fetch all Foos that Bar references to in the instance of Bar whose id is equal to ?.

Edit: Note that I don't have a two-way-relation between the entities, so Foo doesn't know which Bars have a reference to it. Secondly, the reference from Bar to Foo is of type ManyToMany.

Answer (score 0):

These example are not equals to your, but they are similar:

[Hibernate Criteria Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738555/hibernate-criteria-subquery)

[Hibernate Criteria With Property Not In (Subquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635404/hibernate-criteria-with-property-not-in-subquery)

You can use them as example.

Answer (score -2):

Something like:

```
List<Foo> foos = session.createCriteria(Foo.class).createAlias("bar", "bar").add(Restrictions.eq("bar.id", 12345)).list();
```

Corresponds to:

```
class Foo {
   Bar bar;
}

class Bar {
   long id;
}
```

Comment: Like I said, Foo does NOT have a reference to Bar, it's only Bar that has references to to Foo.