# Hibernate Criteria Subquery

Tags: java, hibernate, subquery

I need to do this SQL query with detachedCriteria:

```
SELECT g.id FROM games g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM users_games ug WHERE ug.user_id = 1 AND g.id = ug.game_id)
```

The idea is to get the ids from the games that aren't owned by the user.
I tried like 10 different approaches with detachedCriteria but I get the "Unknown entity: null" MappingException
The code should look like:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserGame.class, "ug")
   .add(Restrictions.eq("ug.user.id", 1))
   .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("ug.game.id","u.id"));
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Game.class, "g")
   .add(Subqueries.notExists(subquery));
```

Setting also the projections to return only the id of the games.

Any ideas?
I think Hibernate has some trouble joining the queries with no alias.
Adding alias works but the results are quite wrong.

Comment: Are you not mapping an association between "games" and "user_games" in your objects / mappings?

Comment: user_games has a mapping to games but not viceversa

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add an alias, as follows:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserGame.class, "ug")
   .addAlias("ug.user", "user")
   .add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", 1))
   .addAlias("ug.game", "game")
   .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("game.id","u.id"));
```

That should help

Answer (score 13):

You need a projection and specifies which attribute that needs to be matched.

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UserGame.class, "ug")
.add(Restrictions.eq("ug.user.id", 1))
.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("ug.game.id","u.id"))
.setProjection(Projections.property("ug.game.id"));

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Game.class, "g")
.add(Property.forName("g.id").notIn(subquery));
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -8):

Try

```
SELECT g.id FROM  users_games ug join ug.game g
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WHERE ug.user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Downvoting because OP's question was about how to do this in Hibernate, not in raw SQL. Also the "FROM WHERE" would be a syntax error in SQL.