# OR clause in LEFT_JOIN in hibernate criteria

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

How can provide OR clause in LEFT_JOIN in hibernate criteria.

```
Criteria mainCrit=hibernateSession.createCriteria("Main.class");    
Criteria aPropertyCrit=mainCrit.createCrieria("child",CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

It generates sql as

```
select this_.Id,this_childId....
from main as this_
left join child as child1_ on child1_ .id=this_.childId
where.....
```

And I need to generate the sql as

```
select this_.Id,this_childId....
from main as this_
left join child as child1_ on child1_.id=this_.childId or child_.ParentId=this_.childId
where.....
```

How do I provide OR clause in LEFT_JOIN in above criteria.

Comment: You may use hibernate conjuction/disjunction to do this.

Comment: have you ever managed to solve this? if yes please share the possible solution

Answer (score 0):

The extending of the JOIN ... ON part, could be done, even with Criteria API. But only to be more restrictive, i.e. adding the **AND** part.

Take a look on the overloads of the [`createCriteria`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createCriteria%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.sql.JoinType,%20org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29) method, mostly the last parameter **withClause**:

```
Criteria createCriteria(String associationPath,
                        String alias,
                        JoinType joinType,
                        Criterion withClause)
                        throws HibernateException
```

*Create a new Criteria, "rooted" at the associated entity, assigning the given alias and using the specified join type.*

Parameters:

- associationPath - A dot-seperated property path
- alias - The alias to assign to the joined association (for later reference).
- joinType - The type of join to use.
- **withClause** - The criteria to be added to the join condition (ON clause)

In fact, any other approach *(e.g. adding the OR)*, is breaking the mapping principal, introducing the ability to have the cross join at the end. see [Hibernate criteria: Joining table without a mapped association](https://stackoverflow.com/a/720894/1679310)

Comment: Criteria mainCrit=hibernateSession.createCriteria("Main.class","main");   Criteria aPropertyCrit=mainCrit.createCrieria("child","child",JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,Restrictions.eqProperty("main.childid","child.parentid")); Now it inserts left outer join child child_ on this_.childid=child_.Id and ( this_.SectionId=child_.parentId ) . And I wanted OR clause instead of AND in the generated sql.

Comment: In the first paragraph I am explaining that the only way, how to work with JOIN ... ON is with the **AND**. There is no support for OR, because that would break the mapping and realtionship. That's the correct ORM behaviour

Comment: So now how do I achieve the result I wanted. I guess I would now try to do it with DetachedCriteria. Any inputs from your end would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What I would suggest is to go with the `Subquery` filtering, I.e. Create a SQL Script, returning the ID we want to be used for filtering and then wrap it in `DetachedCriteria`. Add a Criterion as a Restriction. Please, try to check the basic concept here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637204/1679310. We can use OR expression wrapping two subqueries (child id and child.parentId) either...