# Criteria (NOT IN)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

please, help me:

I have next tables:

**Unit**

- id
- name

**User**

- id
- name

**Rate**

- unit_id
- user_id

I do not understand how to create correct structure of criteria from SQL:

Code:

```
SELECT * FROM Unit WHERE id not in (SELECT unit_id FROM Rate WHERE user_id = 55);
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635404/hibernate-criteria-with-property-not-in-subquery) answer. But I do not understand how to make Condition linked to another Table (Entity).

Comment: Answer you provided is related to Criteria API, not HQL. Switch to Criteria api. Start with `session.createCriteria(Unit.class)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your tag, I think you need the Criteria view of your SQL query; so assuming `Unit` and `Rate` classes:

```
// This is the subquery
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Rate.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("user_id", 55))
    .setProjection(Projections.id())

// This corresponds to (SELECT * FROM Unit WHERE id not in (subquery))
Criteria criteria = session
    .createCriteria(Unit.class)
    .add(Subqueries.notIn("id", subquery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that IN would be the most appropriate in this case. Try an inner join to link up the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Unit INNER JOIN Rate ON Rate.unit_id = Unit.id 
    WHERE Rate.user_id = 55
```